# JQueryBuilder save rules in a sql table

Tags: javascript, c#

What do you think should be the best sql db table structure to save the rules on it?

rules

```
"{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "column2",
      "field": "column2",
      "type": "double",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "74"
    },
    {
      "id": "column3",
      "field": "column3",
      "type": "boolean",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "is_null",
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "condition": "OR",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "column1",
          "field": "column1",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "abc"
        },
        {
          "id": "column2",
          "field": "column2",
          "type": "double",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql db store it as varchar after stringifying as json. I have not found a better solution.